# Not So Basic Div Alignment?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am somewhat new to CSS and thought I was trying to do something simple.
I am creating a responsive page. My goal is to accomplish the following:
Anything smaller than 768px - center each div horizontally. That is happening just fine.
Between 768px and 1024px, Center the main container on the page, with the two divs side by side main container div. Everything is currently not centering.
1024px wide and above - image div on left, text on right - flush to edge of nav. 
I am getting super wonky behavior here.
I am fairly certain that I have missed something fairly obvious since I am very new to this and have jumped headfirst into making something I thought was simple. I have been looking at this for quite some time. Could someone attempt to explain this to me for this scenario? Am I nullifying something by declaring referencing code it in my media queries (I did notice I had an issue since I declared mismatched properties at an earlier time)?

```
    <body>
    <header>
        <img class="style-logo" src="Prism_images/RuckerLogo.png" alt="Logo">
        <nav class="style-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="Content">
    <div class ="style-img">
            <img src="Prism_images/Miles---Headshot_200.png">
    </div>
    <div class="style-main" id="Text">
        <p>premire cabinetmaker</p>
    </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
 header {
    padding: 20px;
}

.style-logo {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.style-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
}

.style-nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #414040;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding: 2px;
}
.style-img {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 200px;
}

.style-main {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 450px;
}
.style-main p {
    color: slategrey;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    display:block;
}
#Content{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

/*Tablet View*/

@media (min-width: 768px){

    body {
        max-width: 778px;
    }
    .style-logo {
        float: center;
    }
    .style-nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .style-nav ul {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .style-img{
        margin-top:0px;
        width:200px;
        display:inline-block;
        }
    .style-main {
        margin-top:0px; 
        display:inline-block;
        }
    #Content {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        display:block;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px){

    body {
        max-width: 1100px;
    }

    .style-logo {
        float: left;
    }

    .style-nav {
        float: right;   
    }
    .style-img {
        margin-top: 40px;
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .style-main {
        padding:20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to center everything ^^

```css
div {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>I'm centered<div>
```

Comment: I placed this code, top level, outside of my classes (below header).
Neither snippet did anything to help my alignment issue...

Comment: So, inside each individual class?

Comment: Where is needed

Comment: Thank you, I played with it and managed to figure out everything but one issue using your help!

Comment: Mark if i helped

Answer (score 0):

That or this.

```
div {
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```